# Firebase 'GET' API returning loads of uneccesarry data

Tags: json, firebase, api, express, google-cloud-firestore

I have a get request in a node server using express. Instead of returning the data as simple objects, it's giving me lots of unnecesary stuff like the private key, data types etc etc.

Something like:

```
{
    "_query": {
        "_firestore": {
            "_settings": {
                "credentials": {
```

PS. Can't show more of the data for obvious reasons, but this should do...

My point was, is there any better way to extract the data, or would I have to line up all of the data field by field? Also, since i'm new to backend work, can you tell me whether a body-parser would help in this situation or not?

This is the GET call:

```
app.get('/api/getAll', async (req: any, res: any) => {
  const allGifts = await db.collection('gifts').get()
  allGifts.docs.map((doc: any) => doc = doc.data());
  res.json(allGifts)
   
})
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you meant to do:

```
app.get('/api/getAll', async (req: any, res: any) => {
  const giftsSnapshot = await db.collection('gifts').get();
  const gifts = giftsSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
  res.json(gifts);
});
```

Comment: Wow, works like a charm. Thanks man. I selected this as correct. Tried to upvote it couldn't as reputation is too low...

Comment: @Sarmad Thanks, no problem. Try to avoid using `any`, most of the time the errors are really telling you about a problem.

Comment: I know. It's just that I normally use Angular, and there I pre define interfaces and never ever use 'any'. This was the first time using node and i was trying to shortcut. Thanks...